# Running a web application (WAR) with embedded Jetty

Tags: java, windows, embedded-jetty

I have a java war that is being run through Jetty.  It has been working on multiple Windows 7 computers for years.  But now a new installation on a Windows 7 computer is producing errors and I don't understand the errors.  I am posting below the log up until the point of the error:

```
C:\Users\QT\Desktop\vcctl\scripts>cd ..\src

C:\Users\QT\Desktop\vcctl\src>java -classpath "lib/derby.jar:lib/derbytools.jar" -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys=20000 -jar "VcctlWrapper.jar"
2016-03-21 15:42:11.866:INFO::AWT-EventQueue-0: Logging initialized @204ms
Current relative path is: C:\Users\QT\Desktop\vcctl\src
2016-03-21 15:42:11.969:INFO:oejs.Server:AWT-EventQueue-0: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225

Mar 21, 2016 3:42:13 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Users/QT/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-vcctl.war-_vcctl-any-7374762875405590280.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml
Mar 21, 2016 3:42:13 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Users/QT/Desktop/vcctl/src/lib/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml
Mar 21, 2016 3:42:13 PM org.apache.struts.config.impl.ModuleConfigImpl addAction Config
WARNING: Overriding ActionConfig of path /my-files/viewImage
Mar 21, 2016 3:42:13 PM org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin initDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
2016-03-21 15:42:13.626:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:AWT-EventQueue-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@3c6dee0f{/vcctl,file:/C:/Users/QT/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-vcctl.war-_vcctl-any-7374762875405590280.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{C:\Users\QT\Desktop\vcctl\src/vcctl.war}
2016-03-21 15:42:13.635:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:AWT-EventQueue-0: FAILED ServerConnector@3ba4f2fd{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner.startJettyServer(webServiceRunner.java:98)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner.<init>(webServiceRunner.java:40)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner$1.run(webServiceRunner.java:107)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
2016-03-21 15:42:13.639:WARN:oejuc.AbstractLifeCycle:AWT-EventQueue-0: FAILED org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server@4a4cdea2: java.net.BindException: Address already
in use: bind
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:279)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractNetworkConnector.doStart(AbstractNetworkConnector.java:80)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.doStart(ServerConnector.java:218)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:337)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner.startJettyServer(webServiceRunner.java:98)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner.<init>(webServiceRunner.java:40)
    at vcctl.webServiceRunner$1.run(webServiceRunner.java:107)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$300(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

On my other Windows 7 computers, the log message looks like this:

```
C:\Users\bullard\Desktop\vcctl\scripts>cd ..\src

C:\Users\bullard\Desktop\vcctl\src>java -classpath "lib/derby.jar:lib/derbytools.jar" -Dorg.eclipse.jetty.server.Request.maxFormKeys=20000 -jar "VcctlWrapper.jar"
2016-03-21 17:34:04.520:INFO::AWT-EventQueue-0: Logging initialized @172ms
Current relative path is: C:\Users\bullard\Desktop\vcctl\src
2016-03-21 17:34:04.598:INFO:oejs.Server:AWT-EventQueue-0: jetty-9.1.3.v20140225
Mar 21, 2016 5:34:05 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Users/bullard/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-vcctl.war-_vcctl-any-9120726856785823814.dir/webapp/WEB-INF/lib/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml
Mar 21, 2016 5:34:05 PM org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet initChain
INFO: Loading chain catalog from jar:file:/C:/Users/bullard/Desktop/vcctl/src/lib/struts-tiles-1.3.8.jar!/org/apache/struts/tiles/chain-config.xml
Mar 21, 2016 5:34:05 PM org.apache.struts.config.impl.ModuleConfigImpl addAction Config
WARNING: Overriding ActionConfig of path /my-files/viewImage
Mar 21, 2016 5:34:05 PM org.apache.struts.tiles.TilesPlugin initDefinitionsFactory
INFO: Tiles definition factory loaded for module ''.
2016-03-21 17:34:05.955:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:AWT-EventQueue-0: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@1ac6103{/vcctl,file:/C:/Users/bullard/AppData/Local/Temp/jetty-0.0.0.0-8080-vcctl.war-_vcctl-any-9120726856785823814.dir/webapp/,AVAILABLE}{C:
\Users\bullard\Desktop\vcctl\src/vcctl.war}
2016-03-21 17:34:05.971:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:AWT-EventQueue-0: Started ServerConnector@146eb1b{HTTP/1.1}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2016-03-21 17:34:05.971:INFO:oejs.Server:AWT-EventQueue-0: Started @1623ms
```

Comment: see the exception: `java.net.BindException: Address already in use` and pczeus answer...

Comment: There is definitely another process listening on port 8080 already.  I am trying to get the sysadmin for that computer to stop the process if it is not needed (it's not my computer).  Failing that, I will try to edit the jetty.xml file as pczeus suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This occurs when another instance of Jetty or another process is running on the same port your Jetty server is attempting to run on. Jetty runs on default port 8080. So either you have another Jetty instance or maybe a Tomcat server running on that server occupying port 8080 (or whatever port you configured).

You can modify the `jetty.xml` file and update the `jetty.port` by changing this line:

```
<Set name="port"><SystemProperty name="jetty.port" default="80"/></Set>
```

But before doing that, I would check for processes in the `taskmgr` like jetty or tomcat currently running. You can also check `netstat -a -b` for running processes and the port they are using.